# The entity or complex type 'Model.Type' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Хочу получить объект с помощью LINQ. Но выдает ошибку.
The entity or complex type 'Shop.ProductCart' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

```
ProductCart product = context.PC_Games
            .Where(g => g.ID == id)
            .Select(g => new ProductCart
            {
                ProductID = g.ID,
                Name = g.Name,
                Category = g.Category.Name,
                ShoppingCartID = HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID
            }).SingleOrDefault();

public partial class ProductCart
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ShoppingCartID { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }

    public virtual ShoppingCart ShoppingCart { get; set; }
} 

public partial class PC_Games
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public string Developer { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    public string InterfaceLanguage { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string OS { get; set; }
    public string Processor { get; set; }
    public string Memory { get; set; }
    public string Graphics { get; set; }
    public string DirectX { get; set; }
    public string Network { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set; }
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

В чем проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по всему, `ProductCart` у вас - это замапленная через L2S сущность. Экземпляры замапленных классов нельзя создавать внутри LINQ запросов через new - это ограничение L2S.

Перепишите код на выборку нужной игры, и отдельно от нее - создание корзины. Примерно так:

```
var gameInfo = context.PC_Games
            .Where(g => g.ID == id)
            .Select(g => new 
                {
                    g.ID,
                    g.Name,
                    Category = g.Category.Name
                })
            .SingleOrDefault();

ProductCart product = new ProductCart
            {
                ProductID = gameInfo.ID,
                Name = gameInfo.Name,
                Category = gameInfo.Category,
                ShoppingCartID = HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему добавив `.ToArray()` после `.Where()`.